# CSS: How to increase distance between two elements?

Tags: html, css

My page has `div` element containing `span` and `table`

```
<div id="mainContent">
    <span id="text:>
         Description of items
    </span>

    <table id="tblContent">

    .....

    </table>
</div>
```

In my CSS I have the following:

```
#tblContent
{
    width:100%;
    border:1px solid black;
    border-collapse:collapse;

}

#tblContent td, #tblContent th
{
    border:1px solid black;
    text-align:center;
}
```

How can I define 20px distance between my `table` and `span` element?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are looking for [`margin`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/margin).

> The margin CSS property sets the margin for all four sides. It is a
>   shorthand to avoid setting each side separately with the other margin
>   properties: margin-top, margin-right, margin-bottom and margin-left.

Try this:

```
#tblContent {
    margin-top:20px;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can define your `span` to `display: block` and then add either padding or margin to it like this:

```
#text {
    display:block;
    margin: 20px;
}
```

How you apply this distance is up to you however.